# Group Policy Update Confirmation

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, group-policy, windows-xp, domain-controller

Server OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard (Domain Controller)

Client OS - Windows XP and Windows 7 (Desktops and Laptops)

I have implemented some Group Policy Objects including Group Policy Preference on all of the clients.

How can I verify if the Group Policy Objects are updated on all the client systems?

One method is to visit each client run manually the `gpresult` command on command prompt and check the output of this to determine if the required Group Policy Object has been applied.

Another method would be to go to the Domain Controller > `Group Policy Management` > `Group Policy Results` and check whether the Group Policy Objects have been applied or not. (In order to do this, the desktops and laptops must be online).

Laptops may or may not be connected to the LAN.

Is there any other way I can automatically get a report of the Group Policy Objects that have been applied as soon as a laptop is connected to the LAN or is there another way to get this information for all desktops and laptops.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gpresult` remotely with the `/s` option.  With a list of computer names you want to query, you could theoretically script this, using the return status of `ping` to filter out hosts that aren't on the network, and do it periodically.

Another thing you can do is create a login script which calls gpresult and does whatever you want with the result.  You can use `/x` or `/h` to write the results to a file based on something like `\\server\share\%COMPUTERNAME%-results.xml` if you want (or just redirect the text output to a file using the redirection operator `>`).

I don't think you can trigger this just from the laptop coming onto your network; no hook for that comes to mind.